# "Invalid connection string format" error when trying to connect to Oracle using TNS alias that contains dot character

Tags: java, oracle, scala, jdbc, tnsnames

I am trying to connect to Oracle database using TNS.

The problem is that TNS alias contains dot, so when I am specifying url like this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNS.ALIAS
```

I've got...

```
oracle.net.ns.NetException: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"
```

...during creation of connection.

I know that dot character is a problem, because after removing it from `tnsnames.ora` file connection to database works.

My question is - is it possible to escape dot character somehow? Maybe there is some connection parameter that can be setup to allow dot character in alias? I would like to avoid removing dot from `tnsnames.ora` since i am getting the file from outside source.

Here are the options that I've already tried that gave me the same error:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@"TNS.ALIAS"
jdbc:oracle:thin:@\"TNS.ALIAS\"
jdbc:oracle:thin:@`TNS.ALIAS`
jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNS\.ALIAS - this one is not compiling
jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNS\\.ALIAS
jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNS&#46;ALIAS
jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNS\".\"ALIAS
jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNS%2eALIAS
```

Here are the options that resulted with `oracle.net.ns.NetException: could not resolve the connect identifier`:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNSALIAS
jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNS-ALIAS
jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNS_ALIAS
```

Additional context:

- I am trying to create Java's `DataSource` (`OracleDataSource` to be
  strict) in Scala (it is Play Framework - but I am not using Play's
  way of creation of DB connections - I am doing it manually)
- I have SQL Developer that is using exactly the same `tnsnames.ora` file and it is working there
- We are having C# applications that are using exactly the same `tnsnames.ora` file and it is working there (data source is defined like this: `<add name="connectionName" connectionString="Data Source=TNS.ALIAS;"/>`

Comment: I don't know the answer. However, would it help if you enclosed *something* into double quotes? Such as `jdbc:oracle:thin:@"tns.alias"`

Comment: @Littlefoot thank you for suggestion, but sadly it gives the same error

Comment: So, did you try with `String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin@\"tns.alias\"";`, escaping the double quotes?

Comment: @MickMnemonic - yes I tried also what you suggested - error is the same

Comment: You  need set  `System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "C:\\app\\product\\12.2.0\\client_1\\network\\admin");`  set to the location of the `tnsnames.ora`

Comment: @DmitryDemin I have this variable set up - without it TNS would not work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem - I was using older Oracle driver (`ojdbc7.jar` for version `12.1.0.1`) after change to newer one (`ojdbc8.jar` for version `12.2.0.1`) lookup by TNS alias started to work - there was no need to escape anything

Answer (score 1):

You need set

```
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin","C:\\app\\product\\12.2.0\\client_1\\network\\admin");
```

set to the location of the `tnsnames.ora`

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBConnect {
    public Connection connection;

    public DBConnect() {
    }

    public void connect() throws Exception {
        String connectString;
        System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "C:\\app\\product\\12.2.0\\client_1\\network\\admin");
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        connectString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@esmdj.test";
        System.out.println("Before DriverManager.getConnection");
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectString, "scott", "tiger");
            System.out.println("Connection established");

            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception inside connect(): " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBConnect client = new DBConnect();

        System.out.println("beginning");
        try {
            client.connect();
            System.out.println("after Connected");

            client.connection.close();

            System.out.println("after close");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
                client.connection.close();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Close Connection Exception : " + ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}


C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin>java -classpath  .  DBConnect
beginning
Before DriverManager.getConnection
Connection established
after Connected
after close
```

tnsnames.ora

```
esmdj.test =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxx.xxx.yyy.zzz)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = ESMD)
    )
  )
```

Comment: I have TNS location setup. But I am seeing that you are using `DriverManager` to create connection (I am using `DataSource`) - I will try also use it to see if it change anything for me