# How to connect to Oracle Cloud DDBB using JDBC Thin Driver and Oracle Wallet

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am following the [guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-20656D84-4D79-4EE9-B55F-333053948966) to connect from a java application using the IDE IntelliJ to an Oracle Cloud Database.

I meet the [prerequisites](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-EBBB5D6B-118D-48BD-8D68-A3954EC92D2B) since:

- I have a Database in Oracle Cloud service
- I downloaded the wallet and I placed the files in the src directory of my workspace.
- I am using last JDK 14
- I am using the ojdbc8.jar
- And I downloaded as well the oraclepki, osdt_cert, and osdt_core jars, all of them added as java libraries in my test project

The recommended BD_URL is never working. I always get: **java.net.UnknownHostException and oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection**

```
DB_URL= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=testgerard_high)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=testgerard_high)))"
```

Then I found in [Oracle support](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=249272212021220&id=1457274.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=gydl1iqzq_259) that it could be added to the wallet directory, but the same issue.

```
DB_URL= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=testgerard_high)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=testgerard_high))(SECURITY = (MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY = src\\Wallet_testGerard)))"
```

If I switch to a connection string using 18.3 JDBC driver which should work for my settings, then I get the error: **Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"**

```
DB_URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@testgerard_high?TNS_ADMIN=src\\Wallet_testGerard";
```

Finally, I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57341480/invalid-connection-string-format-error-when-trying-to-connect-to-oracle-using) a way to inform the wallet folder out of the BD_URL so I do not get the invalid format exception:

```
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin","src\\Wallet_testGerard");
```

Now it is trying to connect but it fails after 60 seconds with the **exception:sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

I adapted an oracle example, here is my code:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData; 
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;


public class OracleDataSourceSample
{
    final static String DB_URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@testgerard_high";
    //final static String DB_URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@testgerard_high?TNS_ADMIN=src\\Wallet_testGerard";
    //final static String DB_URL= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=testgerard_high)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=testgerard_high))(SECURITY = (MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY = src\\Wallet_testGerard)))";

    final static String DB_USER = "hr";
    final static String DB_PASSWORD = "hr";

    public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin","src\\Wallet_testGerard");
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
        ods.setURL(DB_URL);
        ods.setUser(DB_USER);
        ods.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);

        // With AutoCloseable, the connection is closed automatically.
        try (OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection)
                ods.getConnection()) {
            // Get the JDBC driver name and version
            DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("Driver Name: " + dbmd.getDriverName());
            System.out.println("Driver Version: " +
                    dbmd.getDriverVersion());
            System.out.println("Database Username is: " +
                    connection.getUserName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running java code from Windows or Linux environment?

Comment: I am using Windows.

Comment: Thanks Sam,I tried to add the tns_admin direcotry to the path but nothing changes. The app is already locating the forlder due System.setProperty in my code, I know that because if I change the path there I go back to "could not resolve the connect identifier" NetException

Comment: I meant path in `System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin","src\\Wallet_testGerard");` .I ran your code as it is with  tns_admin/wallet path to windows directory  and it worked fine

Comment: I understand you now, I switched to absolute path `System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin","C:\\Users\\gerar\\IdeaProjects\\M03\\UF6\\OracleSimpleExample\\src\\Wallet_testGerard");` but still **unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

Comment: It is in the tns_admin folder, I haven't modified the content, everything is commented except `oracle.net.wallet_location=(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=${TNS_ADMIN})))`

Comment: I haven't any of those utilities, I will try to download sqldeveloper maybe it will work for the job.

Comment: From SQLDeveloper using the TNS .ora file I get: `Error de E/S: Got minus one from a read call`  `Código de proveedor 17002`

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't changed the connection default settings and now I can connect from SQLDeveloper to a Transaction Processing database in oracle Cloud. No action needed on firewall. Any idea of ​​what is wrong with my java app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested with stand alone jdk 8 and jdk 14 as well as Intellij Community edition(first run firewall blocked intellij).

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
    import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
    import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
    
    
    public class SalesConnection
    {
        final static String DB_URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@oci_adw_high";
        final static String DB_USER = "xxxx";
        final static String DB_PASSWORD = "xxxxx";
    
        public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    
    
             System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin","C:\\app\\oracle\\product\\19\\dbhome_1\\network\\admin");
             System.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.fanEnabled","false");
    
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
            ods.setURL(DB_URL);
            ods.setUser(DB_USER);
            ods.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
    
            // With AutoCloseable, the connection is closed automatically.
            try (OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection)
                    ods.getConnection()) {
                // Get the JDBC driver name and version
                DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
                System.out.println("Driver Name: " + dbmd.getDriverName());
                System.out.println("Driver Version: " +
                        dbmd.getDriverVersion());
                System.out.println("Database Username is: " +
                        connection.getUserName());
                printSales(connection);
            }
        }
    
        public static void printSales(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            // Statement and ResultSet are AutoCloseable and closed automatically.
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
              try (ResultSet resultSet = statement
                  .executeQuery("select /* Java Console */PROD_ID, CUST_ID from sales fetch first 10 rows only ")) {
                System.out.println("PROD_ID" + "  " + "CUST_ID");
                System.out.println("---------------------");
                while (resultSet.next())
                  System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1) + " "
                      + resultSet.getString(2) + " ");
              }
            }
          }
}
```

Try to run this code change table and column names

Source of this [code](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java)

**Edit:**
Compiling and executing from command prompt

```
javac -cp "C:\ojdbc8-full\*;" SalesConnection.java

java -cp "C:\ojdbc8-full\*;" SalesConnection
```

Comment: I run your code with the firewall disabled and still unable to instantiate the connection, same error **unable to find valid certification path to requested target**. I reinstalled IntelliJ and tried with jdk 8,11 and 14. it should be something in my project configuration. How did you included the requested .jar files as libraries in the project structure? Thanks

Comment: Here [link](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=335007200682113&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=PROBLEM&id=2416548.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=7o2zkvlwh_4) it says something about cacerts that should be in %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts, I have the file, but don't know how to download the certs and put it there, anyway I don't think taht it is really needed.

Comment: At least you narrowed down to intellij settings.Go to project root folder right click open module settings or `F4` ,on the left pane select libraries and add directory path to all jar files e.g in my case [ojdbc8-full](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-ucp-19-6-c-downloads.html) directory

Comment: Thanks @Sam, finally I have managed to instantiate the connection. The problem was I just was adding individually the .jar files mentioned in the [prerequisites](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-EBBB5D6B-118D-48BD-8D68-A3954EC92D2B). When using the **ojdbc8-full** it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

ojdbc8-full.zip contains oraclepki.jar, osdt_core.jar and osdt_cert.jar which are required for connecting to Oracle autonomous database. However, you can get JDBC driver along with other additional libraries using these maven co-ordinates.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupid>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupid>
    <artifactid>ojdbc8-production</artifactid>
    <version>19.7.0.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Refer to the [Maven Central Guide](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html) for more information